# Angular 4 Application in SAP WebIde and SAP Cloud Platform

Tags: angular, sap-web-ide, sap-business-technology-platform

We are planning to create AngularJS application in SAPWebide and deploy and run the application on SAP Cloud platform. I am sure that we can do this with Angular 1 but I came to know that Angular 2 and 4 has some problem with SAP Cloud while developing in Webide and running the app in cloud. (something related to Node.js)

Could someone please explain, is this possible?

Regards,
MS

Answer (score 2):

What I understand from [here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/825270ffffe74d9f988a0f0066ad59f0/CF/en-US/a71bf8281254489ea8be6e323199b304.html) your need the Fullstack Web IDE which is related to the use of SAP HANA.
(normal web IDE can be used without HANA).
Furthermore you need an upgrade tp SAP HANA XS, which supports connecting via [node.js](https://www.sap.com/developer/tutorials/xsa-node-dbaccess.html)
I will try linked tutorial and update this comment.